# Is there a natural equivalent of consistency for the case of prediction?

Tags: predictive-models, consistency

Consistency is generally understood to be a pretty basic requirement for a decent estimator of a model parameter or other population quantity. If your estimator isn't consistent, then it won't converge in probability to the true value as the sample size increases, as an estimator ought to.

What might be an equivalent notion in a predictive context? Generally we can't hope for a predictive model to converge on giving exactly the right prediction every time as its training data increases in size, because we expect there to be some unpredictable variability. For example, if $X$ is standard normal, a model might learn more about the distribution of $X$ given more and more independent observations of $X$, but without other relevant data, its RMSE for predicting $X$ can never get below $1$, because that's the SD of $X$.

Is there some analogous notion of consistency that's suited for prediction? A sense in which a predictive model will converge on being as good as it can be, allowing for unpredictable variability?

Comment: Something like BLUPs?